# Jquery removing highlighted class does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-lists

I have many `<li>` elements that some of them are in normal state and some part are in highlighted state (has "hasNews" class):

```
<ul class="companies">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <li id='company_@(item.Id)' data-id='@item.Id' @{if (item.hasNews) { <text>class="hasNews"</text>} } >
                  <a>@item.Name</a>
        </li>
      }
</ul>
```

I want when I click any `<li>`, to send it's Id to controller, to set that company *as read* and if callback is true then to remove "hasNews" class from that `<li>` .
I have method in controller to do this. But I need a help in jquery to remove "hasNews" class from clicked `<li>` item if callback is true. With following code I send request to controller, do my operation and return *false* or *true*. But that `<li>` item is highlighted still:

```
$('.companies li ').click(function (e) {
    url = '@Url.Action("SetCompanyNewsAsRead", "Company")';
    var data = { id: $(this).attr('data-id') };
    $.post(url, data, function (result) {
      if (result.success) {

      $(this).removeClass('hasNews');  //this does not remove "hasNews" class.

     }
   });
});
```

How can I solve this issue?

**Edit:**
I want to add: one of `<li>` items is  'current'. I did this with:

```
$('#company_' + currentItemId).addClass('current');
```

this work. May this prevent "hasNews" class removing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `this` in the inner (callback) function is not the same as in the outer function - `this` is set according to how a function is called, it's definitely not inherited from the containing function. Save a reference to it in a variable in the outer function and the inner one can access it:

```
$('.companies li ').click(function (e) {
    url = '@Url.Action("SetCompanyNewsAsRead", "Company")';
    var theLI = this,   // <--------- Save reference to this
        data = { id: $(this).attr('data-id') };
    $.post(url, data, function (result) {
      if (result.success) {

        $(theLI).removeClass('hasNews');  //this does not remove "hasNews" class.

     }
   });
});
```

For a more complete explanation about how `this` works in JavaScript have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

EDIT: To answer your edit, no, the presence of other classes should make no difference.